# Hadoop: error while format namenodes - 'Could not find or load main class namenodes'

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

After I installed all needed for uploading hadoop (unix on win-7-64bit), and I got this error (bold):

> roeygol@roeygol-PC /etc/hadoop-2.5.1/bin 
>   $ ./hdfs namenodes -format
>   **Error: Could not find or load main class namenodes**

I defined the needed nodes as requested and all other configurations, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hdfs namenode -format 

its "namenode" not "namenodes"
```